# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java

i am trying with connecting to MySQL through JDBC (included the JARs)
but i have observed the following scenarios 
1: When i connect with MySQL within PSVM it will work fine with same JAR
2:When i connect with MySQL without PSVM ie i have defined my method which returs Connection 
 but here it is throwing following Exception  please help me out guys....

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.Dbconnection.DBconnection.doGet(DBconnection.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You'll need to add the mysql jar to your application server's class-path.